# Import many python files in bash script

Tags: python, bash

I have a problem with the import file in the bash script.

My project directory looks like this:

```sh
project
├── folder1
│   └── file1.py
├── folder2
│   └── file2.py
├── data
│   └── example.txt
├── utils
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── globals.py
└── run.sh
```

The `globals.py` file contains some config global variables that will be used in the whole project.

I want to write a bash file to run all `.py` files like this `run.sh`:

```sh
conda activate pyenv

# Step 1.1
python folder1/file1.py data/example.txt >> data/output_1_1.txt

#  Step 1.2
python folder2/file2.py data/output_1_1.txt >> data/output_1_2.txt
```

But then I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "folder2/file2.py", line 15, in <module>
    from utils import globals
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

This is my `file2.py` where I import `utils.globals`:

```py
import sys

sys.path.append("../")  # Add "../" to utils folder path
from utils import globals
```

When I run each file individually, it works fine, but I don't know why it doesn't work when I run `source run.sh`.

Comment: Create `__init__.py` file making it a package

Comment: @bigbounty I just updated my directory, I already have `__init__.py` in the `utils` folder.

Comment: @bigbounty I create a `__init__.py` file in every folder but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28154841/9500955) points out it is not good to use a relative path when the project structure is complex.

So I change my project directory to this to make it a package like @bigbounty's suggested:

```sh
project
├── package
│   ├── folder1
│   │   └── file1.py
│   ├── folder2
│   │   └── file2.py
│   ├── data
│   │   └── example.txt
│   └── utils
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── globals.py
└── run.sh
```

In the `file2.py`, change the `import` to this:

```py
from package.utils import globals
```

The `run.sh` file:

```sh
conda activate pyenv

# Step 1.1
python -m package.folder1.file1 package/data/example.txt >> package/data/output_1_1.txt

#  Step 1.2
python -m package.folder2.file2 package/data/output_1_1.txt >> package/data/output_1_2.txt
```

To run the bash script, `cd` to the `/project`:

```
(base) user@user1:~/project$ source run.sh
```

Then it works as expected.

Comment: Indeed.  Something I always try to point out is that, except in some very special cases, if you find yourself writing `sys.path.insert...` in your package you're probably doing something wrong =)

Comment: @Iguananaut I did not notice that before. Now the project contains more and more files which makes me realize this problem.